# What could cause an object disapear only in Edit Mode?

Tags: objects

I accidentally clicked <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. Then if I go to object mode I can see it.If I switch to edit mode It disappears.I tried to uncheck it in user preferences too and in object tab too. Maybe I accidentally clicked something else.

[image]

Comment: just disable it in the Properties panel > Object > Display > Texture Space

Comment: Can you add your blend file to your question? Grab the URL of the question
Go to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/
Select the blend file
Add the url of the question
Grab the url that results
Go back to the question and edit it

Add the new url to the bottom of the post

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> moves object's texture space - it has nothing to do with visibility.

You may have some modifier the effects of which is not visible in edit mode, or, more likely, you hid everything with <kbd>h</kbd>. To unhide the geometry hidden, you can go to edit mode and hit <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to unhide everything.

To reset the location of object's texture space if you moved it accidentally, you can set the values to 0 in the Properties Editor, Mesh tab, under Texture Space:

[image]